# saveUninitialized: false does not work after express-flash added

Tags: express, session

I am a hobby coder and I started to learn building a website using express, pug and mongodb which users can create their own account and login in it.

I tried to save session of only logged-in users to database.
so I set the value of saveUninitialized false and it actually worked
but after I added flash then it saves the session data whenever user logged-in or not.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URL }),
  })
);

app.use(flash()); //<== it works again if this line is removed.
```

Comment: if i understand correctly you are trying to use this npm module to display flash mesages? npmjs.com/package/flash

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to use the flash node module for express. When looking for the node module I found this module here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash

according to documentation the usage is slightly different from your implementation.

after running `npm i flash` or `yarn add flash` you can use the module like this:

```
app.use(session()); // session middleware
app.use(require('flash')());
 
app.use(function (req, res) {
  // flash a message
  req.flash('info', 'hello!');
  next();
})
```